# Comparing console line to string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm working with my first `VB.NET` console app, and I'm having a hard time with a (probably) very simple concept. I need to compare something that a user types to a series of strings.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Is there a 2nd IIS Server? (y/n)")
    If Console.ReadLine() = "Yes" Or "yes" Or "Y" Or "y" Then
        Servers.IISsvr2 = Console.ReadLine()
    End If
```

I know the = operator isn't correct here, because that's for a Boolean. Should I make the check into a series of Boolean checks? Or is there a better way I can handle this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=` operator is perfectly correct; it’s the rest of your `Or` operands that are wrong!

This is a pretty common mistake that people make in every language, and the fact of the matter is, it just doesn’t work. Programming languages aren’t magic. `Or` takes one operand and another and returns either a boolean or an integer. It has a lower precedence than `=`. You have to specify the comparison each time, or it’ll just always be `True`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Is there a 2nd IIS Server? (y/n)")
Dim line As String = Console.ReadLine()

If line = "Yes" Or line = "yes" Or line = "Y" Or line = "y" Then
    Servers.IISsvr2 = Console.ReadLine()
End If
```

Also, use `OrElse` to prevent unnecessary comparisons (it’s almost always what you want when the operands are boolean):

```
Console.WriteLine("Is there a 2nd IIS Server? (y/n)")
Dim line As String = Console.ReadLine()

If line = "Yes" OrElse line = "yes" OrElse line = "Y" OrElse line = "y" Then
    Servers.IISsvr2 = Console.ReadLine()
End If
```

`Select Case` can also be fun in some cases<del>, but it’s probably not appropriate here</del>:

```
Select Case Console.ReadLine()
    Case "Yes", "yes", "Y", "y"
        Servers.IISsvr2 = Console.ReadLine()
End Select
```

Prompts, anyone?

```
Function BooleanPrompt(prompt As String) As Boolean
    Do
        Console.Write("{0} (y/n) ", prompt)

        Select Case Console.ReadLine().ToLower()
            Case "y", "yes"
                Return True
            Case "n", "no"
                Return False
        End Select
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `SELECT CASE` be appropriate here? It seems like that's the simplest to read and handles the scenarios I need to test for. Less lines, too, and there's one less variable to store/collect.

Comment: @SeanLong: Well, usually you wouldn’t use it for just one and convert to lowercase or something. You’re right, though… it’s probably actually a good choice.

Comment: That's a lot of options though. I'll probably be using that Prompt function in the future for this app. I find it odd that this is really, really fun to me.

Comment: @SeanLong: VB.NET is a ton of fun! Don’t let anybody tell you otherwise =D

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the read line into a variable and then test that variable:

```
Console.WriteLine("Is there a 2nd IIS Server? (y/n)")
Dim str as string =  Console.ReadLine()
If str.ToUpper() = "YES" Or str.ToUpper() = "Y" Then
    Servers.IISsvr2 = Console.ReadLine()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
If {"Yes","yes","Y","y"}.Contains(Console.ReadLine()) Then
```

If you may have a lot of options for `yes`, I suggest having a `HashSet(Of String)`, where these values would be pre-populated, then doing `Contains` on that.